# Has --dco-restore bricked any drives in hdparm?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, hdparm

In Linux, in [hdparm](https://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm), I want to run the `--dco-restore` command to ensure no malware is hiding in the hidden part of the drive. However I am worried about the prospect of bricking my drive in the process.

Is it **known** that this command causes such a risk to the drive? No research I have found suggests that. Other than the man page saying that the command is extremely risky since it deletes all your data in the process, which should be obvious to anyone using hdparm.